# É possível executar teste unitário de classe com herança?

Tags: java, tomcat, testes-de-unidade

Preciso fazer teste unitário de `PlanilhaReader` porém esta extende `ArrayList<String>` e sobrescrevo o método **contains**. Há alguma maneira de executá-lo?

```
@Component
public class PlanilhaReader extends ArrayList<String> {

    final String UPLOAD_PATH = PropertiesSingleton.getValue("api.upload.dir");

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        String paramStr = (String)o;
        for (String s : this) {
            if (paramStr.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public BasicDBList readMetadados(Planilha planilha) {...}
}
```

Teste

```
public class PlanilhaReaderTest {

    @Test
    public void testReadMetadados() throws Exception {
        PlanilhaReader reader = new PlanilhaReader();
        Planilha planilha = new Planilha().setPath("552d4cf1ccf2c0a58301a744/55163343b0df070bbc66e1bb6e0c3f9b.xlsx");
        reader.readMetadados(planilha);
    }
}
```

Ao compilar obtenho o erro:

```
Hot Swap failed
         Tomcat 8.0.18: hierarchy change not implemented; 
         Tomcat 8.0.18: Operation not supported by VM; 
         PlanilhaReaderTest: hierarchy change not implemented; 
         PlanilhaReaderTest: Operation not supported by VM; 
         PlanilhaReaderTest: hierarchy change not implemented; 
         PlanilhaReaderTest: Operation not supported by VM
```

Comment: Pergunta boba? Porque ela herda de `ArrayList<String>`? Isso me parece ser uma péssima ideia!

Comment: Por causa do "contains", preciso que ele não seja case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Herdar de `ArrayList<String>` é ruim. Aliás herdar de qualquer classe de `Collection`, a menos que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo é ruim. O motivo é que o código das `Collection`s está fora do seu controle e ao herdar de uma delas [algo de ruim pode acontecer](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XSTR-746).

É possível testar a sua subclasse adequadamente? Sim. É fácil de fazer isso? Não. O motivo é que a sua subclasse depende fortemente da superclasse. No seu caso, ao fazer isso, a sua `Collection` pode criar alguns comportamentos inesperados. Por exemplo:

```java
if (lista.contains("abacaxi")) lista.remove("abacaxi");
```

Isso daí vai falhar misteriosamente se o que houver na sua lista for "ABACAXI" ao invés de "abacaxi". Isso ocorre porque o comportamento da superclasse tem algumas condições implícitas que a subclasse inocentemente acaba violando.

De fato é possível consertar-se a sua subclasse. Mas na prática você terá que introduzir um monte de mudanças distintas e acabará por reescrever a superclasse inteira dentro da subclasse e provavelmente não é isso o que você quer.

Por outro lado, você provavelmente vai argumentar que você só usa esta classe para uma finalidade específica e que não precisa de todos os funcionamentos herdados da superclasse. Neste caso, o que você herda da superclasse é denominado de *herança maldita*, comportamentos que não são desejados na subclasse e estão lá porque vieram da superclasse.

Qual é a solução para isso? Abandonar a herança e usar composição:

```
@Component
public class PlanilhaReader {

    final String UPLOAD_PATH = PropertiesSingleton.getValue("api.upload.dir");

    private final List<String> lista;

    public PlanilhaReader() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>(10);
    }

    public boolean contains(String paramStr) {
        return this.lista.contains(paramStr.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        this.lista.add(s.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
    }

    public BasicDBList readMetadados(Planilha planilha) {...}
}
```

E como resultado, a sua classe agora é bem mais fácil de ser testada. O número de interações entre os dados e entre os métodos desta classe é muito menor. Também é muito mais difícil usá-la de forma inadequada ou inesperada.

Observe que para simplificar, eu decidi colocar todos os elementos na lista já convertidos para uma forma canônica, a fim de fazer o `contains` original funcionar.

Comment: Tive que lidar dessa forma para poder fazer o teste. Desconsiderando essa situação específica, não é possível fazer testes unitários em classes "filhas", então?

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais É sim, mas você sempre tem que ter em mente que todos os comportamentos da classe pai estão lá juntos. E a menos que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo, alguns destes comportamentos da classe pai poderão vir a te atrapalhar. No fim das contas, hoje em dia, a herança de classes é considerada algo ruim na orientação a objetos, pois promove o alto acoplamento ao invés do baixo acoplamento. A herança é algo a ser evitado a menos que você tenha uma forte razão para usar.

Comment: Passei tanto tempo da minha vida resolvendo problemas que eu criava herdando as coleções do C#... Maldita "escola" de orientação a objetos que apresenta a herança como o recurso mais bacana e "must have" para o seu código.