# Como evitar que o objeto ultrapasse os limites da tela?

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Comecei a programar um joguinho onde um objeto se move pela tela por intermédio das setas do teclado. A dificuldade que encontrei é o fato de que o objeto ultrapassar o `JFrame`, ou seja, não existe nada para bloquear a passagem no limite do `JFrame`.

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver esse problema, ou pelo menos uma indicação de um caminho que eu deveria fazer para alcançar êxito neste objetivo.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Jogo1 extends JFrame{ //Herda para usar JFrame

String n = "0";
JLabel labelFlappy = new JLabel(n);

int posPrincX = 300;
int posPrincY = 300;

public Jogo1(){
    editarJanela();
    editarComponentes();
    addMovimento();
}

public void addMovimento(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){ //Teclado
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyCode()); //Exibe código da tecla pressionada
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
                posPrincY -= 20;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
                posPrincY += 20;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
                posPrincX -= 20;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
                posPrincX += 20;
            }
            labelFlappy.setBounds(posPrincX, posPrincY, 180, 90); //Atualiza posição
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   

        }           
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { //Ao clicar no objeto em questão
            posPrincX = (int)(Math.random() * 650);
            posPrincY = (int)(Math.random() * 700);
            labelFlappy.setBounds(posPrincX, posPrincY, 180, 90);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }   
    });
}

public void editarComponentes(){
    labelFlappy.setBounds(posPrincX, posPrincY, 180, 90);
}

public void editarJanela(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Encerra ao fechar 
    setSize(750, 700); //Tamanho 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Centraliza
    setVisible(true); //Torna visível
    setLayout(null); //Permite redimensionamento de cada componente
    setResizable(false); //Impossibilita o redimensionamento pelo usuário
    setTitle("Magisterix"); //Título

    add(labelFlappy);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Jogo1();
}}
```

Comment: Fornecá um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executarmos seu código e detectar o problema,  sem ele fica dificil ajudar

Comment: _Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página [ask] para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta._

Comment: Esses icones nao deixam o codigo executar, o que pode atrapalhar simular o problema. Tente editar o codigo de formar que seja possivel executar sem precisar dos icones.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam desfiz sua edicao pois ela removeu trechos importantes do código, e isso não é recomendavel de se fazer nas edicóes.

Comment: Importação é importante? nunca coloquei os imports nas minhas perguntas, as vezes são várias e várias linhas e considero irrelevante na pergunta, pelo menos nessa

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam sim, é importante, se foi adicionado, nao deve ser removido.

Comment: como posso editar para não necessitar das imagens?

Comment: @Eddunic ai vc precisa testar seu proprio codigo sem as imagens nos labels e ve se da pra reproduzir o problema da mesma forma.

Comment: Acabei de editar

Comment: Executei e nao identifiquei o problema mencionado na pergunta, se possivel, explique como voce fez para que o objeto saia da area da tela.

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja no método addMovimento. Meu objetivo é fazer com que o objeto possa ir até a borda do JFrame e não passe de lá. Quando eu compilo e guio o objeto, o mesmo ultrapassa a borda do JFrame. Eu quero impor um limite na borda dessa tela para o movimento do objeto.

Comment: @Eddunic seu código não reproduz muito bem e tem outros problemas, mas veja a resposta abaixo onde sugiro uma solucao, mesmo sem ter conseguido entender o objetivo desse codigo.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Eu particularmente, acho que as importações ajudam. Já vi algumas questões onde o erro estava no `import` devido a haver classes com nomes iguais em pacotes diferentes. Além disso, para ser um MVCE 100% arrumadinho tem que ter os imports, até para poupar quem for responder de ter que consertar o código dado para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Encontrei a solução, o que deveria ser feito era simples. Apenas criar condições de pausa e retorno de acordo com as coordenadas do objeto na tela. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer assim:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Jogo1 {

    private static final int KEY_CODE_DOWN = 38;
    private static final int KEY_CODE_UP = 40;
    private static final int KEY_CODE_LEFT = 37;
    private static final int KEY_CODE_RIGHT = 39;

    private static final int DISTANCIA_PASSO = 20;
    private static final int LARGURA_INICIAL_TELA = 750;
    private static final int ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA = 700;
    private static final int POSICAO_X_INICIAL = 300;
    private static final int POSICAO_Y_INICIAL = 300;
    private static final int LARGURA_FLAPPY_INICIAL = 180;
    private static final int ALTURA_FLAPPY_INICIAL = 90;

    private int posicaoX;
    private int posicaoY;

    public Jogo1() {
        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Magisterix");
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Encerra ao fechar.
        tela.setSize(LARGURA_INICIAL_TELA, ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA); // Ajusta o tamanho.
        tela.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centraliza.
        tela.setVisible(true); // Torna visível.
        tela.setResizable(false); // Impossibilita o redimensionamento pelo usuário.
        tela.setLayout(null); // Permite redimensionamento de cada componente.

        JLabel labelFlappy = new JLabel("0");
        labelFlappy.setOpaque(true);
        labelFlappy.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        tela.add(labelFlappy);
        posicaoX = POSICAO_X_INICIAL;
        posicaoY = POSICAO_Y_INICIAL;
        labelFlappy.setBounds(posicaoX, posicaoY, LARGURA_FLAPPY_INICIAL, ALTURA_FLAPPY_INICIAL);

        tela.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KEY_CODE_DOWN) {
                    posicaoY -= DISTANCIA_PASSO;
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KEY_CODE_UP) {
                    posicaoY += DISTANCIA_PASSO;
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KEY_CODE_LEFT) {
                    posicaoX -= DISTANCIA_PASSO;
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KEY_CODE_RIGHT) {
                    posicaoX += DISTANCIA_PASSO;
                }
                posicaoX = limitar(0, posicaoX, tela.getContentPane().getWidth() - labelFlappy.getWidth());
                posicaoY = limitar(0, posicaoY, tela.getContentPane().getHeight() - labelFlappy.getHeight());
                labelFlappy.setBounds(posicaoX, posicaoY, labelFlappy.getWidth(), labelFlappy.getHeight());
            }
        });

        tela.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                posicaoX = (int) (Math.random() * (tela.getContentPane().getWidth() - labelFlappy.getWidth()));
                posicaoY = (int) (Math.random() * (tela.getContentPane().getHeight() - labelFlappy.getHeight()));
                labelFlappy.setBounds(posicaoX, posicaoY, labelFlappy.getWidth(), labelFlappy.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }

    private static int limitar(int min, int meio, int max) {
        return meio < min ? min : meio > max ? max : meio;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Jogo1::new);
    }
}
```

O truque está em limitar `posPrincX` e `posPrincY` ao tamanho da janela (ou `posicaoX` e `posicaoY`, vez que renomeei as variáveis). Para isso, uso o método `limitar(int, int, int)`.

Fiz mais algumas outras mudanças no seu código:

- Só criar, interagir, usar e acessar componentes Swing dentro da EDT. Para isso, uso o `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`. Veja mais sobre isso [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132) e [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132).
- Preferir usar composição do que herança, e portanto não herdar de `JFrame`. Falo sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58766/132). Também abordo essa questão (e muitas outras coisas) [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276869/132).
- Usar [números mágicos](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Magic_Number) não é uma boa prática de programação. Fiz o seu código sem usar números mágicos e também de uma forma que se o tamanho da tela ou o tamanho do label mudarem, ele não vai ficar bagunçado e vai se ajustar à mudança sozinho.
- Pintei o `JLabel` de amarelo para que você possa ver exatamente onde ele está e qual é o seu tamanho.
- Alterei o nome de algumas variáveis para ficarem mais representativos.
- Use `KeyAdapter` e `MouseAdapter` ao invés de implementar diretamente `KeyListener` e `MouseListener` para não pecisar ter aquele monte de métodos vazios.

Comment: Cara, obrigado por essa grande dica! Vou começar a mudar alguns modos de programar.

Answer (score 5):

Para evitar que componentes que se movem excedam a área da tela, você pode utilizar um método que cheque se as posições X e Y novas, somadas com a largura e altura total do componente, excedem o tamanho da tela nas duas direções, e quando excederem, não movimentar mais o componente ou aplicar alguma valor negativo pra ele não ficar preso no canto. O método para verificar isso, baseado no seu código, pode ser mais ou menos assim:

```
private boolean excedeuAreaDaTela(int posX, int posY) {
    return posX < 0 || posX + 180 > 750 || posY < 0 || posY + 90 > 700;
}
```

Para usar, basta envolver com uma condicional a linha que você altera a posicão do componente:

```
if (!excedeuAreaDaTela(posPrincX, posPrincY)) {
    labelFlappy.setBounds(posPrincX, posPrincY, 180, 90); // Atualiza posição
}
```

Quando o método retornar `true`, significa que se o componente se mover para as coordenadas informadas, excederá o tamanho que você definiu para a tela, a condicional não vai permitir o movimento neste caso.

Comment: Acredito que o certo seja limitar o sprite ao tamanho da tela, de forma semelhante ao que o Victor fez. Me corrija se eu estiver enganado, mas me parece que o código acima não está fazendo isso.

Comment: @Piovezan o código acima faz exatamente isso, só fui mais simplista.

Comment: Entendi. É que para mim pareceu que ele evita passar do tamanho máximo mas não posiciona o sprite exatamente no tamanho máximo. Assim este fica sempre um pouco antes do tamanho máximo.

Comment: Downvoter, se voce realmente entende do assunto, porque não me mostra onde está o erro no código? ;) mostre que você votou consciente e não porque é uma pessoa boçal e implicante.