# Como mockar uma função private no JUnit

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit, mockito

Eu tenho uma classe principal `Usuario` que estende (`extends`) uma classe abstrata chamada `Sessao`, e usa uma função da `Sessao` chamada `obterDados()` que pega os dados da sessão e devolve em um um objeto `SessaoTO`. Eu preciso mockar essa função pra ela retornar o objeto mockado e seguir com o fluxo.

Eu já tentei mockar a classe `Sessao` da seguinte maneira:

```
// Declaração feita na classe
@Mock
Sessao sessao;

...

// Declaração feita na função de teste
SessaoTO sessaoTO = new SessaoTO();
sessaoTO.setCpf("47566611100");
sessaoTO.setNome("Gaus");
sessaoTO.setSigla("user");

when(sessao.obterDados()).thenReturn(sessaoTO);
```

O problema é que na hora da execução está dando erro de NullPointer porque esse mock não está funcionando. Já tentei usar o `@InjectMocks`, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Olá! Compartilhe o código da classe Usuario e Sessao, se possível. Confesso que, já me adiantando, Usuario extender uma classe chamada Sessao não me parece uma abordagem correta.

Comment: Não fui eu que fiz a implementação do código da classe. Apenas estou fazendo os testes unitários.

Comment: Não sei se nas versões mais novas o mockito permite mock de métodos privados, mas dá pra fazer usando powermock: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-verify-private-behavior

Comment: Muito relacionado, mas não é duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269196/132

Answer (score 1):

Não dá para mockar um método privado. A ideia do mock é você fornecer implementações falsas de objetos e não de métodos isolados (ainda mais quando privados). Além disso, um método privado é por definição, uma funcionalidade interna de um objeto escondida do mundo exterior. Trata-se de uma coisa como aquele trecho de código que para não ficar duplicado foi isolado em um método a parte. Assim sendo, não deveria haver motivo para tentar se mockar um método privado.

A ideia do teste com mock é você fornecer ao objeto que está sendo testado, implementações mock dos outros objetos com o qual ele irá interagir.

No entanto, no seu caso, parece que não é isso que você está tentando fazer, e sim mockar apenas alguns dos métodos do objeto. Não é assim que deveria ser. Ou o objeto contém a implementação completa que você quer exercitar ou ele é um mock. Não há meio termo.

Assim sendo, o seu problema é que você quer injetar o `SessaoTO` que deveria ser produzido. Isso sugere que você poderia usar o padrão de projeto *Strategy* ou *Factory*. Ao invés de o seu objeto `Sessao` fabricar o `SessaoTO` em um método privado, ele pediria para o *Strategy* ou o *Factory* nele injetado fazê-lo. Dessa forma, você poderia mockar esse *Strategy* ou *Factory* para fornecer o `SessaoTO` que você quer.

Outras perguntas que acho relevantes ao seu caso:

- [Quando usar mock de métodos estáticos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269196/132)
- [É possível executar teste unitário de classe com herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58754/132)
- [Qual a melhor maneira de definir o acesso aos métodos de uma classe que quero usar para testes unitários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313829/132)

Comment: Eu estou tentando mockar uma parte do processo do qual não é possível executar em um teste JUnit por precisar de todo o  resto do processo funcionando (incluindo a parte de rede). Esse método do qual estou tentando mockar não consegue buscar os dados corretamente e acaba causando um erro de NullPointer no meio do teste.

Comment: @Isdeniel Novamente, você deve mockar objetos, e não métodos isolados. Não é desse jeito que você está tentando fazer que as coisas funcionam, e tentar forçar a barra não vai funcionar. Separe o conteúdo do método privado em uma outra classe representada por uma interface criada para isso e então daí sim você vai conseguir mockar isso facilmente. A ideia aqui é exatamente separar as partes uma das outras adequadamente para poder usar os mocks, e se você não está conseguindo usá-los, é um forte sinal de que as coisas não estão corretamente separadas.

Comment: @Isdeniel Eu até poderia te indicar como reorganizar as coisas para conseguir essa separação, mas o código que está na pergunta é insuficiente para que eu possa apontar isso.