# Preciso de ajuda em um método

Tags: java, swing

Estou com um problema relacionado a um jogo que estou criando onde o personagem joga uma bomba na posição que ele se encontra. Na primeira execução do método `bomba()` a execução sai como o ordenado.

Porém, nas demais execuções do método ele só executa uma parte do método.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}

class Personagem extends JLabel{

    public Personagem(int x ,int y) {
        player(x,y);
    }

    ImageIcon persoImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("personagem.gif"));
    public JLabel personagem = new JLabel(persoImg);

    public void player(int x,int y) {
        personagem.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
    }

}

class Game extends JFrame {

    public Game() {
        bombas.carregarbomba();
        movimento();
        componentes();
        janela();
    }

    int y = 300;
    int x = 400;
    int contador = 0;

    public  Personagem perso = new Personagem(x, y);
    public Bomba bombas = new Bomba();

    ImageIcon bombaImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bomba.gif"));


    public JLabel bombfoto = new JLabel(bombaImg);
    public JTextField text = new JTextField(":" + contador);
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public void componentes() {
        Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 25);
        bombfoto.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

        text.setBounds(60, 0, 50, 50);


    }

    public void janela() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(150, 100, 1000, 700);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        componentes();

        add(bombas.bombaJLabel[bombas.getCont()]);
        add(perso.personagem);
        setVisible(true);

    }


    public void movimento() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char movimento = e.getKeyChar();
                if (movimento == 'w') {
                    y -= 20;
                }
                if (movimento == 's') {
                    y += 20;
                }
                if (movimento == 'd') {
                    x += 20;
                }
                if (movimento == 'a') {
                    x -= 20;
                }
                if (movimento == 'e') {
                        bombas.bomba(x, y);
                        bombas.setCont(contador);
                        contador++;
                }

                perso.personagem.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);

            }
        });
    }

}

class Bomba extends JLabel {

    ImageIcon bombaImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bomba.gif"));
    ImageIcon explosao = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("explosao.gif"));
    public int cont = 0;

    public JLabel[] bombaJLabel = new JLabel[8];
    int xbomb = 0;
    int ybomb = 0;

    public void carregarbomba() {
        for (int i = 0; i < bombaJLabel.length; i++) {

            bombaJLabel[i] = new JLabel(bombaImg);
            bombaJLabel[i].setSize(50, 50);
            bombaJLabel[i].setVisible(false);

        }
    }

    public void bomba(int x, int y){

        try {
                xbomb = x + 30;
                ybomb = y + 30;
                bombaJLabel[cont].setLocation(xbomb, ybomb);
                bombaJLabel[cont].setVisible(true);

                if (bombaJLabel[cont].isVisible()) {

                    ActionListener detonar = new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                            bombaJLabel[cont].setIcon(explosao);
                            bombaJLabel[cont].setBounds(xbomb -= 180, ybomb -= 300, 400, 400);

                            ActionListener duracaoexplocao = new ActionListener() {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                    bombaJLabel[cont].setVisible(false);


                                }
                            };

                            javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1200, duracaoexplocao);
                            timer.setRepeats(false);
                            timer.start();
                        }
                    };
                    javax.swing.Timer timer2 = new javax.swing.Timer(2000, detonar);
                    timer2.setRepeats(false);
                    timer2.start();
                }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {}

    }

    public int getCont() {
        return cont;
    }

    public void setCont(int cont) {
        this.cont = cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: copiei um link para o github com o projeto completo

Comment: Cara, pense no lado de quem vai te ajudar, você acha legal forçar o cara a ter que ir num link externo pra acessar teu codigo e te ajudar? E quem não poder acessar esse link? Por isso, é importante e recomendável que você forneça um **[mcve]** e adicione-o na pergunta, clicando em **[edit]**.

Comment: @Donztt Como disse o Articuno, o ideal é que todo o código necessário para reproduzir o problema esteja na pergunta, e links sejam apenas complementos. Links podem ficar fora do ar ou mudar (e até ser bloqueado por firewall de empresas, dependendo do link e da empresa) e aí quem for tentar te ajudar não terá a informação completa. Se o código original é muito grande, tente reduzi-lo e crie um **[mcve]** <-- leia esta página, tem várias dicas de como arrumar seu código para postá-lo aqui.

Comment: coloquei a parte principal do problema,espero que ajude

Comment: @Donztt teu codigo é um **[mcve]**? Se eu colar na minha IDE, ele vai executar? Porque se nao for, nao adianta colar o codigo inteiro. Recomendo que visite o link que tanto eu quanto o hkotsubo sugeriu e tente criar um exemplo que qualquer um possa testar, sem testar fica dificil te ajudar.

Comment: acredito que execute o problema quanto a isso é em relação as imagens que o programa utiliza

Comment: Então vc entende q nao é possivel outros executarem. Como vamos te ajudar se não podemos executar? Novamente, recomendo que acesse o link para aprender a transformar seu codigo num **[mcve]** para que assim seja possivel testarmos e ajudarmos.

Comment: Estou vendo o seu código e sei que posso ir lá no github pegar o resto porque o que foi postado aqui está incompleto. No entanto, você não descreveu qual é o seu problema. Qual é o método para o qual você precisa de ajuda? Qual é o problema que você está tendo? O que há de errado nesse código?

Comment: agora é só copiar e colar que está funcionando

Comment: Estou vendo o seu código. Acho que você andou se esquecendo de algumas palavras-chave `static`.

Comment: eu não estou acostumado a criar tudo em uma classe e acabei esquecendo mesmo kk

Comment: Estou escrevendo uma resposta para a sua pergunta. Quando terminar eu posto ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz isso:

```
public class Macaco extends Animal {
    private Banana banana = new Banana();
}
```

Você está dizendo que:

- Todo macaco é um animal.
- Cada macaco tem uma banana.

Quando você faz isso:

```
public class Macaco extends Animal {
    private Banana[] banana = new Banana[8];
}
```

Você está dizendo que:

- Todo macaco é um animal.
- Cada macaco pode ter 8 bananas.

Quando você faz isso:

```
class Bomba extends JLabel {
    public JLabel[] bombaJLabel = new JLabel[8];

    public void carregarbomba() {
        // blablabla
    }
}
```

Você está dizendo que:

- Toda bomba é um `JLabel`.
- Uma bomba pode ter até 8 `JLabel`s.
- Cada bomba pode carregar bombas.

Aí que as coisas estão erradas. Afirmar que cada bomba pode ter até 8 `JLabel`s é absurdo. Ainda mais considerando que `Bomba` já é um `JLabel`. Também dizer que cada bomba pode carregar bombas também está errado.

O que você queria era carregar as bombas na classe `Game`. Afinal de contas um `Game` tem várias `Bomba`s. Aliás, utilizar arrays para isso é uma abordagem horrível. Estamos em 2018, e não em 1995, e portanto use as listas que o Java oferece há mais de 20 anos ao invés de ficar se torturando ao tentar controlar isso usando arrays. Aliás, já que você vai ter uma lista de bombas, eis o que você faz:

- Quando o usuário aperta <kbd>E</kbd> você **instancia** uma bomba (usando `new`) e a coloca na lista.
- Quando a bomba explodir, você a remove da lista.
- Crie cada bomba de forma similar a que você usa para criar personagens.
- Abandone essa ideia de pré-carregar 8 bombas invisíveis no início! Isso é uma ideia muito ruim!
- Esqueça aqueles malditos contadores!

Outro problema:

```
class Personagem extends JLabel{
    ImageIcon persoImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("personagem.gif"));
    public JLabel personagem = new JLabel(persoImg);
}
```

Isso está dizendo que:

- Todo personagem é um `JLabel`.
- Cada personagem tem uma imagem.
- Cada personagem tem um outro personagem que é um `JLabel`.

Novamente, isso está bastante errado. Se o `personagem` já é um `JLabel` por meio de herança, então não tem sentido usar composição também e dizer que ele tem um personagem. Ou você usa herança ou usa composição, mas nunca deve usar os dois simultaneamente. Vejo que no seu código, você parece utilizar o `JLabel` da composição, então elimine o da herança.

Vejo que isso é um trabalho de TCC. Então:

- Uma forma muito fácil de tomar porrada do pessoal da banca na hora da sua defesa é colocando o modificador `public` nos seus atributos. Qualquer livro decente sobre Java avisa logo nos primeiros capítulos que isso é uma péssima ideia e explica o porquê.
- Esquecer de colocar o `private` e deixar a visibilidade de pacote também não é uma boa ideia.
- Siga rigorosamente as regras de nomenclatura e indentação do Java porque você não vai querer nenhum membro da banca enchendo o saco por causa disso.
- Também sugiro usar os recursos que as versões mais recentes da linguagem (especialmente a partir da 8) usam quando for pertinente, em especial os lambdas.

Outra coisa importante é nunca manipular componentes Swing fora da *Event-Dispatch Thread*. Veja [nessa minha outra resposta o porquê](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132).

Herança não é algo considerado muito legal. Falo disso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58766/132) e também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276869/132) (junto com muitas outras coisas). Isso significa que fazer `Game` usar um `JFrame` ao invés de herdar de `JFrame` é uma boa ideia. Retirar todos os `extends JLabel` também é uma boa ideia.

Também recomendo [essa outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296689/132).

Observe que você está chamando o método `componentes()` dentro do construtor de `Game` e dentro de `janela()`. Isso significa que está chamando duas vezes. Isso não faz sentido. Aliás, recomendo colocar tudo isso direto no construtor de `Game` pois nesse caso você não está ganhando nada ao dividi-lo em métodos.

As URLs das imagens devem ser carregadas em variáveis estáticas.

Isso daqui:

```
perso.personagem.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
```

Está violando o encapsulamento de `Personagem`. No entanto, você já tem o método `player` (que recomendo renomear para `posicionar`) para fazer isso, então basta usar esse método.

Nesse lugar:

```
public JTextField text = new JTextField(":" + contador);
```

O valor de `contador` vai ser zero quando isso for executado. No entanto, você nunca adiciona esse componente à janela, então isso acaba não servindo para nada.

Essas linhas estão sobrando de bobeira, pois isso já está dentro da classe `Bomba`, não precisa ficar em `Main`:

```
ImageIcon bombaImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bomba.gif"));
public JLabel bombfoto = new JLabel(bombaImg);
```

Outras coisas que estavam de bobeira:

```
private JPanel contentPane;
Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 25);
```

Os campos `x` e `y` que representam a posição do personagem deveriam estar dentro da classe `Personagem`. Ao invés de alterá-los dentro da classe `Game`, o certo é que a classe `Personagem` ofereça métodos para manipular a sua posição (`subir()`, `descer()`, `esquerda()` e `direita()`, por exemplo). Aliás, essa posição nem precisa ser armazenada na classe `Personagem` pois pode ser obtida do `JLabel` por meio do método `getLocation()`.

O tamanho da explosão é 350x350 e não 400x400. Mas você pode usar os métodos `getIconWidth()` e `getIconHeight()` e calcular as posições a partir do tamanho da imagem. A vantagem disso é que se você mudar o tamanho da imagem, não tem que sair arrumando um monte de números.

Outros detalhes importantes:

- Sem ter um `setLayout(null);` coisas muito estranhas acontecem.
- Sem ter um `repaint()` fica sujeira na tela quando componentes são removidos.

O código resultante ficou assim:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Game::new);
    }
}

class Personagem {

    private static final URL GIF = Personagem.class.getResource("/personagem.gif");

    private final Game jogo;
    private final JLabel label;

    public Personagem(int x, int y, Game jogo) {
        this.jogo = jogo;
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(GIF);
        this.label = new JLabel(img);
        jogo.add(label);
        label.setBounds(x, y, img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight());
    }

    public void subir() {
        posicionar(0, -20);
    }

    public void descer() {
        posicionar(0, 20);
    }

    public void direita() {
        posicionar(20, 0);
    }

    public void esquerda() {
        posicionar(-20, 0);
    }

    private void posicionar(int dx, int dy) {
        Point p = label.getLocation();
        int x = (int) p.getX();
        int y = (int) p.getY();
        label.setLocation(x + dx, y + dy);
    }

    public Bomba colocarBomba() {
        Point p = label.getLocation();
        int x = (int) p.getX();
        int y = (int) p.getY();
        return new Bomba(x, y, jogo);
    }
}

class Game {

    private final JFrame janela;
    private final List<Bomba> bombas;
    private final Personagem bomberman;

    public Game() {
        this.bombas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.janela = new JFrame();
        this.bomberman = new Personagem(300, 400, this);
        janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        janela.setBounds(150, 100, 1000, 700);
        janela.setLayout(null);
        janela.setVisible(true);
        janela.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char movimento = e.getKeyChar();
                if (movimento == 'w') bomberman.subir();
                if (movimento == 's') bomberman.descer();
                if (movimento == 'd') bomberman.direita();
                if (movimento == 'a') bomberman.esquerda();
                if (movimento == 'e') bombas.add(bomberman.colocarBomba());
            }
        });
    }

    public void removerBomba(Bomba b) {
        bombas.remove(b);
    }

    public void add(JLabel c) {
        janela.add(c);
    }

    public void remove(JLabel c) {
        janela.remove(c);
        janela.repaint();
    }
}

class Bomba {

    private static final URL GIF_BOMBA = Bomba.class.getResource("/bomba.gif");
    private static final URL GIF_EXPLOSAO = Bomba.class.getResource("/explosao.gif");

    private final Game jogo;
    private final JLabel label;

    public Bomba(int x, int y, Game jogo) {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(GIF_BOMBA);
        label = new JLabel(img);
        this.jogo = jogo;
        jogo.add(label);
        label.setBounds(x, y, img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight());

        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, evt -> detonar());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void detonar() {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(GIF_EXPLOSAO);
        int w1 = label.getWidth();    // Largura da bomba.
        int h1 = label.getHeight();   // Altura da bomba.
        int w2 = img.getIconWidth();  // Largura da explosão.
        int h2 = img.getIconHeight(); // Altura da explosão.
        Point p = label.getLocation();
        int x = (int) p.getX();
        int y = (int) p.getY();
        label.setIcon(img);
        label.setBounds(x + w1 / 2 - w2 / 2, y + h1 - h2, w2, h2);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1200, evt -> remover());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void remover() {
        jogo.removerBomba(this);
        jogo.remove(label);
    }
}
```

Ainda há mais umas mudanças que deveriam ser feitas, em especial porque o modelo MVC não está sendo respeitado. Mas isso já deve servir para fazer o que você quer e já deve resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Donztt Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Comment: Ta certo! Obrigado pela atenção